# Submenu navigation is not floating left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the navigation  menu then drop down and further sub menu 
The problem which i am facing the sub menu is not floating in  left rather its coming down side

the html code which i have written as

```css
.mainmenu {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("img/mainmenu_area_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0;
    height: 53px;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    padding: 17px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li:hover> a,
.mainmenu ul#nav li.current{
    background: #11c3f1 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
/*=================
DropDown Menu
===================*/
#nav > li {
    position: relative;
}
#nav > li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
 z-index:9999;top: 100%;
 visibility:visible;
}
#nav > li ul {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -2px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 204px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  z-index:-99999;
  top: 150%;
  visibility:hidden
}
#nav > li ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;

}
.mainmenu ul#nav li ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 80px 0;
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}


#nav ul .subNav ul {
 display: none;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: outside none none;
}
#nav ul .subNav:hover ul{
 display: block;
 
}
#nav ul .subNav ul li {
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-top: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav ul .subNav ul li a {
 color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    padding: 17px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 float: left;
 width:100%;
}
#nav li.subNav ul li a:link, #nav li.subNav ul li a:visited {
 color: #333;
}
#nav li.subNav ul li a:hover, #nav li.subNav ul li a:active {
 color: #F34B2B;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mainmenu nav">
 <nav>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="services.php">Service</a>
 <ul> 
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>                  
   <li class="subNav"><a href="#">Menu2</a>
     <ul class="subNav">
       <li><a href="#">Piano</a></li>                                     <li><a href="#"> Couch</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Appliances</a></li>
      </ul>
          </li> 
   </ul> 
</li> 
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Bring the cursor in the result page you will see the output, I want some one bring cursor to MENU2 it should float to left side rather then down.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean float to the right side? I can see it at the left now.

Comment: Yes, to the right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you needed to have the li containing the subnav be displayed relatively, that way the sub nav menu can be positioned absolutely 200px to the left and a top of 0 in reference to the li.

```css
.mainmenu {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("img/mainmenu_area_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0;
    height: 53px;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.mainmenu ul#nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    padding: 17px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li:hover> a,
.mainmenu ul#nav li.current{
    background: #11c3f1 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
/*=================
DropDown Menu
===================*/
#nav > li {
    position: relative;
}
#nav > li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
 z-index:9999;top: 100%;
 visibility:visible;
}
#nav > li ul {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -2px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 204px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  z-index:-99999;
  top: 150%;
  visibility:hidden
}
#nav > li ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;

}
.mainmenu ul#nav li ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 80px 0;
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}


#nav ul .subNav ul {
 display: none;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: outside none none;
}
#nav ul .subNav:hover ul{
 display: block;
  left:200px;
  top:0; 
}
#nav ul .subNav ul li {
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-top: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav ul .subNav ul li a {
 color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    padding: 17px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 float: left;
 width:100%;
}
#nav li.subNav ul li a:link, #nav li.subNav ul li a:visited {
 color: #333;
}
#nav li.subNav ul li a:hover, #nav li.subNav ul li a:active {
 color: #F34B2B;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu nav">
 <nav>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="services.php">Service</a>
 <ul> 
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>                  
   <li class="subNav"><a href="#">Menu2</a>
     <ul class="subNav">
       <li><a href="#">Piano</a></li>                                     <li><a href="#"> Couch</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Appliances</a></li>
      </ul>
          </li> 
   </ul> 
</li> 
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: .mainmenu ul#nav li { position:relative}, #nav ul .subNav:hover ul{ left:200px; top:0}

Comment: Ops !! Thanks a lot